# Display a custom Wordpress taxonomy tag automatically based on the day of the week?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got a client that wants to display custom taxonomy tags automatically by day of the week in Wordpress. Basically, we'll have a custom post type called "products" and that will have a taxonomy called "day." Within "day" we'll have seven tags, one for each day of the week, and anything tagged with a specific day of the week will display on that day on the home page.

So, for example, if Product A, B & C are all assigned a tag of "Wednesday" within the taxonomy "day" and today is Wednesday, then those items will display on the home page. If products D, E & F are assigned Thursday, they'll show up on Thursday, and so on.

With all that said, the part I need help with is writing a loop that can detect the day of the week and then query the proper taxonomy tag. Does anyone have any idea how to go about this? I really can't find any reference on this and my PHP skills are rudimentary at best. :-/

Here's the loop I'm currently using to display products manually by custom post type, taxonomy & term:

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=products&taxonomy=day&term=wednesday&posts_per_page=10'); ?>
<?php if(have_posts()) : while (have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="archivecustompost">
<div class="archivecustomleftblock">
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_post_thumbnail( array(150,150) ); ?></a>
</div>
<div class="archivecustomrightblock">
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<p class="button"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">Learn More</a></p>
</div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try something like this,

Using **WP_Query**

```
$day = date("l"); // Gives the todays day.
$wpq = array (post_type =>'product','taxonomy'=>'day','term'=>$day);
$query = new WP_Query ($wpq);
```

Using **query_post**:

```
$day = date("l");
$args = 'post_type=products&taxonomy=day&term='.$day.'&posts_per_page=10';
query_posts($args);
```

Comment: So what problem you are facing now ?

Comment: Sorry, my first reply got all mangled up. Anyway, I've updated my original post to show the query that I'm currently using. The problem I'm having is that I'm not entirely sure how to replace my query with yours. I've worked very little with taxonomies and terms so I'm new to this. :-/

Comment: @JoeytheSquid - I have updated my answer with `query_post` method. Please check

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks. I didn't know how to call the variable $day in there. Much appreciated.

Comment: BTW, is there a particular advantage to using WP_Query over query_post in this case?

Comment: @JoeytheSquid Check http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts

Comment: @JoeytheSquid btw accept the answer if your problem is solved by this.